# Kotlin synthetic imports doesn't work and it's now deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

In kotlin to access an element in the layout you do not need to do:

```
val k = findViewById(R......)
```

The element should be automatically imported into the kotlin file that connected to the view F.E if you have a text element in your main activity, in kotlin you access it by using it's id directly in the file that inflates that view and the import should be added automatically like this.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*
```

However in few recent projects I noticed that this does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the Kotlin synthetics have quite a lot of similarities to the View Binding feature. The main advantage view binding has is that it's a bit harder to use the wrong binding class (with synthetics, you could quite easily import the wrong synthetics class if you have views in multiple layouts with the same ID).

I believe it's deprecated for a number of reasons, namely the type safety issue and the fact that it doesn't work with Java.

I've wrote a short tutorial on view binding [here](https://eventcollapse.com/posts/android-view-binding).

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that Kotlin Android Extensions is now deprecated. Here is the guide to use the new method.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Another option is to add the plugin in the app.gradle file.

```
plugins {
...
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

After doing this two questions comes to mind:

1. Why did they remove the imports?
2. isn't the method that they demonstrated just doing the exact same thing as in it's importing the whole view?

Comment: The removed them because they were deprecating them. View binding is completely different than the synthetic view references. View binding is done declaratively. You inflate the views and they are already bound for you. The synthetic view references happen passively. It lazily finds the views in the current layout when you first access them, and if your current view happens not to have the view with that name, you get an exception. This lack of safety is one of the reasons they decided to deprecate. The other reason is that it doesn't work in Java.